# Django dynamic list comprehension filtering between dates

Tags: python, django, list-comprehension

I am using comprehension to filter dynamically between multiple from-to date inputs.
If one of the two has no value, the search should still work.

How can I apply the below logic using django [range operator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#range)?

What I really want is to be able to pass in the filtering `qs = qs.filter(**filters)` and convert it to `qs = qs.filter(date_from1__lt=whatever)`

```
def mail_search(request):
    today_date = datetime.now()

    qs = MailAllocation.objects.filter(cmp_id=cmp_id)

    """comprehension: build a dictionary and use it for filtering queryset dynamically"""
    filters = {
    key: value
    for key, value in request.POST.items()
    if key in ['date_from1','date_to1','date_from2','date_to2','date_from3','date_to3'] 
    }

    qs = qs.filter(**filters).order_by('-creation_date')

    context={
    'dfs_search_results':qs,
    }
    return render(request,'mail_search_results.html',context)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Q objects to chain up your queries so each of your keys will get simplified to the following :-

```
from django.db.models import Q

q1 = Q(creation_date__range=(date_from1, date_from2))
// Build other queries similarly

qs = qs.filter(q1 | q2 | q3)  // The | is the OR operator
```